# How is method reference syntax working in Java 8

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8

I am having some confusion of how method references work in Java 8. I wrote the following code segment for filtering hidden files in a folder. They are producing correct result. I am not understanding -> how method signature of listFiles method is working for option 2 of this code segment.

This is what I found in Java 8 documentation

1. `File[]  listFiles()`
2. `File[]  listFiles(FileFilter filter)`
3. `File[]  listFiles(FilenameFilter filter)`

```
File[] hidden = f.listFiles((p)-> p.isHidden()); //Option 1 - function signature matching (based on my understanding)
for (int i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(hidden[i]);
}
System.out.println("================================");
File[] hidden1 = f.listFiles(File::isHidden); //Option 2 - how this method call is working
for (int i = 0; i < hidden1.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(hidden1[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What is a method refernce**

You can see a method reference as a lambda expression, that call an existing method.

**Kinds of method references**

There are four kinds of method references:

- Reference to a static method: `ContainingClass::staticMethodName`
- Reference to an instance method of a particular object: `containingObject::instanceMethodName`
- Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type: `ContainingType::methodName`
- Reference to a constructor: `ClassName::new`

**How to understand it?**

The following expression that lists all hidden files:
`f.listFiles(p -> p.isHidden());`

This expression is composed by the instance method `listFiles(FileFilter)` and your lambda expression `p -> p.isHidden()` that is *not* a anonymous method but an existing instance method of the class `File`.

Note that `FileFilter` is a functional interface and can therefore be used as the assignment target for a lambda expression or method reference. Hence, you can write your expression `f.listFiles(File::isHidden);`

**Side notes**

1. You don't need the parentheses surrounding the `p`. For a better readibility, I would suggest to replace `(p)` with simply a `p`. Hence, your lambda expression will become `p-> p.isHidden()`.
2. Your for loop can be replaced by an *enhanced* for loop:

```
for (File value : hidden) {
   System.out.println(value);
}
```

**Documentation:**

[Method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

[FileFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html)